# Is there any way to see the requirements for a Gold medal before achieving Silver?

Tags: trials-evolution

In *Trials: Evolution*, I'm wondering if there is any way to see the requirements for a gold medal on a track/tournament without having achieved silver.

When you have no medal, the track/tournament selection screen only shows that you need to pass the track for Bronze. If you achieve Bronze, it then shows you the requirements for Silver. And, if you have Silver, then you can finally see the requirements for Gold. Same would go for Platinum, you have to have Gold. Typically, most tracks require 0 faults for Gold, but I'm more concerned about seeing the time to know if I'm going to achieve that on a track.

So, is there anywhere in game to view the full medal requirements for a track without having earned the previous medals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to check the medal times in-game. Your best bet would be to track down a webpage that lists them (though I haven't had any luck finding one yet).

**Edit: [This site](http://www.ign.com/wikis/trials-evolution/Walkthrough) includes time and fault limits for each track.**